# Angular 2 accessing hardware camera

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ngcordova

I have been trying to get [this](https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera) tutorial working in Angular2.  The problem I am facing is getting navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia working.  The issue is that mediaDevices does not exist on type 'navigator'.

Here is the [media capture and stream](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/) documentation.

I'd like to link more information but I do not yet have the reputation. However, the DefinitelyTyped MediaStream.d.ts is the other resource I've been using.

I hope to get this working by the end of the week, if I get the solution I will post an example on GitHub.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `mediaDevices` is [not yet widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices#Browser_compatibility) - at the very least, you will probably have to find a polyfill to patch it for browsers without support.

Comment: added the link which works in angular 2 4 and 5

Answer (score 7):

[Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX4JT.jpg)

I got it working in a single .ts file, here is the [GitHub example](https://github.com/doorKOnline/ng-video-example).  To navigate directly to the example file go to src/app/example/example.component.ts

To solve the problem I went the object-oriented route.  i.g.

```
var n = <any>navigator;

n.getUserMedia = ( n.getUserMedia || n.webkitGetUserMedia || n.mozGetUserMedia  || n.msGetUserMedia );
```